# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n\int ^{2\pi }_{0}x\sin x (e^{\frac {x}{n}}-1){\rm d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Some one gives a process as follows

\begin{align*} &\lim_{n \to \infty} n\int ^{2\pi }_{0}x\sin x (e^{\frac {x}{n}}-1){\rm d}x\\ =&\lim_{n \to \infty} n\int ^{2\pi }_{0}x\sin x \left(\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x^2}{2n^2}+\cdots\right){\rm d}x\\ =&\int_0^{2\pi} x^2\sin x{\rm d}x\\ =&-4\pi^2, \end{align*}

which is based on Taylor formula.

**This is rigorous?**

Comment: Yes because the Taylor series for $e^x$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be rigourous, unless you justify the fact that we are allowed to bring the limit Inside of the integral.

Anyway here is another proof, let $ n $ be a positive integer, such that $ n\geq 2\pi $ :

If $ x\in\left[0,2\pi\right] $, we have then $ \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{n}}-1}{\frac{x}{n}}-1=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{xy}{n}}-1\right)\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{x}{n}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{y\,\mathrm{e}^{\frac{xyt}{n}}\,\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}y}\leq\frac{x}{n}\,\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{n}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{y\,\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}y}\leq\frac{x}{2n} \cdot $

Thus, we have : \begin{aligned} \left|n\int_{0}^{2\pi}{x\sin{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{n}}-1\right)\mathrm{d}x}-\int_{0}^{2\pi}{x^{2}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\right|&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{x^{2}\sin{x}\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{n}}-1}{\frac{x}{n}}-1\right)\mathrm{d}x}\\ &\leq\frac{1}{2n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{x^{3}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 \end{aligned}

Hence : $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}{n\int_{0}^{2\pi}{x\sin{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x}{n}}-1\right)\,\mathrm{d}x}}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{x^{2}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}=-4\pi^{2} $$